# Adding a ScrollView to previously created ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scroll

I'm working on a Cricket Simulator and have a screen with tons of text boxes for the user to enter a team and info on the players. I now realize that I need that screen to scroll, because the pop up keyboard hides the bottom part of the screen.

Is there a way to make this previously complicated screen scrollable? I know how I'd do it from scratch, by creating a ScrollView and then creating my view on top of it in Storyboard, but is there a way to make it scrollable after previously creating it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can make your current screen as UIView (or even left them as UIViewController, but the view is more obvious), and add this view on top of scroll view from code. Autolayout in this case you have to do from code too.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how? Assuming I have a createViewController: UIViewController.

Comment: @PhilEdge - can you show an image cap of how you have your screen currently laid out? Individual labels, text fields and buttons, with constraints between them? Or a set of subviews? Or are they in a Stack View?

Comment: I could, but I don't know how to upload an image.

Comment: Have you tried selecting all the elements in your view, then (from the top menu bar) selecting `Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View`?

Comment: Thanks. I just did that. It doesn't scroll though, because I guess the view is the same size as the scroll view. How can I make it so that this can scroll? I think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: I'm using the workaround of dismissing the keyboard on return, which works for now

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with the Interface Builder (the Storyboard editor in Xcode). Leave all your elements where they are for now and don't worry about constraint issues until you set everything up. (You could also create everything described here programmatically, but either way you will need a UIScrollView to make content scrollable. Another option would be a UITableView, but that's way more work and you would have to rebuild everything, which is as you said out of the question. Just wanted to mention that to be complete.)

Your ViewController has a Main View. Drag a `UIScrollView` from the Object Library into the View. Give the ScrollView's `Top Anchor`, `Trailing Anchor`, `Bottom Anchor` and `Leading Anchor` a constraint to the Main View with a constant of 0 for each.

The easiest way to add you elements into the Scrollview would be to use a vertical `UIStackView`. In order to do so and not get constraint issues, you need to add a `UIView` as a container into the scrollview. Give the 4 anchors (this time the ones of the container) mentioned above 0-constant constraints to the Scrollview. Also give it an equal width constraint to the Main View.

Now add the StackView into the container and also set its four anchors (this time to the container of course). You can now drag your elements into the StackView. You don't need a `UIStackView` though. You could add all your elements to the container, but the container needs a height and a width constraint. We already set up the width constraint, you would need to do the height constraint yourself based on your elements. The latter would be managed by the `UIStackView` automatically.

Now you can start setting constraints (you won't need height constraints, as the StackView calculates it's height automatically). The ScrollView will need a height and a width for it's content. It automatically get's the height from the StackView. When running on a device the ScrollView will automatically become scrollable, once the contents of the StackView no longer fit the screen. The ScrollView get's it's width from the container which has a set width, since it follows the Main View's width. When setting the anchors be careful that the checkbox for `Constrain to margins` is deselected.

Hope the pictures below help to illustrate my lengthy explanation:

[image: The Structure of the VC]
[image: Make sure this is off (red circle)]